# Unix : hostname return a Russian telecom domain

Tags: security, hostname

I've noticed when typing the command hostname on my mac machine it return :

```
128-75-1-232.broadband.corbina.ru
```

There is nothing on google about it.
The Whois said it's a Russian telecom company.
A coworker of mine also working on mac have the same things.
What does it mean !??

Comment: Is this the content of /etc/hostname file?

Comment: Hi Marek thanks for the answer. It's not a file but the command :
hostname -[option] [file]

Comment: Is it? I am not a mac expert, but in Linux it is a simple text file. Do a `cat /etc/hostname`.